# Multiplication of Set Discrete math

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I ran into some problems.
Do you guys have any ideas about multiplication of set?

For example:

$A = \{1,2,3\},\quad B = \{x,y\},\quad C=\{0,1\}$

What will you do if I want to see: $A\times(B\times C)$

Can you do the binary method?

Comment: Do you mean the cross product of the sets? I.e., $A\times(B\times C)$? Please clarify what is meant by "*"

Comment: i am not sure, the question want me to Find A×(B×C). I suppose they just want me to multiply the sets

Answer (score 16):

The symbol $\times$ is used to denote the ["Cartesian Product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sets: it results in a set with ordered pairs.

The Cartesian product (some call it the "cross product" of sets) $X \times Y$ is defined such that $$X\times Y = \{(x, y)\mid x \in X, y\in Y\}$$

I'll get you started: $$B\times C = \{(x, 0), (x, 1), (y, 0), (y, 1))\}$$

Comment: ok got it. thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: so would it be 
A×(B×C) = {(1,x,0),(1,x,1),(1,y,0),(1,y,1), (2,x,0).....}?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: shouldn't A X (B X C) = {(1, (x, 0)), (1, (x, 1)), (1, (y, 0)), (1, (y, 1)), (2, (x, 0)), ..., (3, (y, 1))} ?